# Starting on web api ( can't locate namespace for HttpClient)

Tags: web-services, http, rest, c#-4.0

I'm starting to work with web api and i'm struggling to build my sample program. I get a compile error "The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found".

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri = "https://raw.github.com/AlexZeitler/HttpClient/master/README.md";
            var httpClient = new System.Net.htt HttpClient();
            httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri).ContinueWith(
                t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I have referenced the namespace Sytem.Net.Http but that does not seem to help.

I wonder if someone can tell me what i'm missing.

Thank is advance
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install this Nuget Package

```
     http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/
```